# How i can reverse this function?

Tags: jquery, function, reverse

How can I reverse the way the following function works? Currently, the nav is open and if the user clicks the `<a>` tag then it closes.

What I really want is `nav` to be initially closed and to open only if the user clicks the `<a>` tag.

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#main_nav li.active').addClass('open').children('ul').show();
        $('#main_nav li.has_sub>a').on('click', function(){
            $(this).removeAttr('href');
            var element = $(this).parent('li');
            if (element.hasClass('open')) {
                element.removeClass('open');
                element.find('li').removeClass('open');
                element.find('ul').slideUp(200);
            } else {
                element.addClass('open');
                element.children('ul').slideDown(200);
                element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp(200);
                element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
                element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
                element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp(200);
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);


//HTML CODE

<div id='main_nav'>
<ul>
<li class='active'><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Products</a>
  <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
           <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
           <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
 <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you show the html code please?

Comment: I add the html code up to my question.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like the code already does both. If the button is clicked a second time, the nav re-opens, right?

If that is the case, then just comment out or remove the first line of code in that function, which opens up the nav menu when the page first loads.

```
// $('#main_nav li.active').addClass('open').children('ul').show();
```

Comment: Yeah, if the button clicked second time  the nav re-opens but i want the nav to be close when the page loads. I tried that you show me but it did not work. Thanks anyway for the respond!